# Define $i: X \to M_f$ by $i(x) = [x, 0]$. Show that $i$ is a homeomorphism to subspace of $M_f$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Define $i: X \to M_f$ by $i(x) = [x, 0]$ and $j: Y \to M_f$ by $j(y) = [y]$. Show that
> $i$ and $j$ are homeomorphisms to subspaces of $M_f$. Here $M_f$ is the mapping cylinder.

I will first try to show the case for $i$. Restrict $i$ so that $i: X \to i(X)$, then $i$ is surjective and since $i(x)=i(x') \implies [x,0]=[x',0]$ and these equivalence classes are singletons $\{(x,t)\}$ and $\{(x',t)\}$ we can conclude that $x=x'$, thus $i$ is injective and therefore a bijection.

Now for $i$ to be a homeomorphism we need to show that it's open. So let $U$ be open in $X$, then $i(U) = \{[x,0] \in M_f \mid x \in U\}$ but I think that this set is just $U \times \{0\}$ (it should be the top face of the mapping cylinder?) so $i(U)$ is thus open and $i$ would be a homeomorphism(?).

Comment: Are you sure that $U \times \{0\}$ is open in $X \times [0,1]$ ? (I had written an answer but there was a big mistake... i'll try to fix it tomorrow if I have some time)

Answer (score 1):

You have a map $f : X \to Y$. The mapping cylinder $M_f$ is defined as the quotient space
$$M_f = (X \times [0,1] + Y)/\sim$$
where $+$ denotes disjoint union and $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $(x,1) \sim f(x)$ . Let $p : X \times [0,1] + Y \to M_f$ denote the quotient map.

You already know that $i : X \to i(X)$ is a continuous bijection. Given an open $U \subset X$, the set $U' =  U \times [0,1)$ is open in $X \times [0,1]$. We have $p^{-1}(p(U')) = U'$, thus $p(U')$ is open in $M_f$. But clearly $p(U') \cap i(X) = i(U)$ which shows that $i(U)$ is open in the subspace $i(X)$ of $M_f$.

Similarly $j : Y \to M_f$ is a continuous injection. Thus $j : Y \to j(Y)$ is   continuous bijection. Given an open $V \subset Y$, the set $V' = f^{-1}(V) \times [0,1] + V$ is open in $X \times [0,1] + Y$. We have $p^{-1}(p(V')) = V'$, thus $p(V')$ is open in $M_f$. But clearly $p(V') \cap j(Y) = j(V)$ which shows that $j(V)$ is open in the subspace $j(Y)$ of $M_f$.